# How to get icon overlays with git-extensions

Tags: git, icons, overlay, tortoisegit

I have been using svn for quite some time now. But now I have shifted to git. As per my findings Tortoise Git does not provide you with a good understanding of how git works, that's why I picked git-extensions.

The problem is that I am used to the overlay icons that Tortoise used to provide me. I really want them while using git. I am not really sure about how we can get these overlays in git-extensions. Can some one tell me how can I get these overlays back on my system?

PS: I don't want to use Tortoise since, it hides the core concept/working of git. Also, my operating system is windows 7.

I am open to other GUI options also, provided they help me understand how git works.

Currently I am using Tortoise with Git extensions. Which is kind of clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any icon overlay proposed by [gitextensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/) (see its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions)).

[image: gitextension menu]

So amongst the other [GUI for Git on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows), one of the most complete would be [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/quick-start.html) (but not free though), and none offers overlays at the Windows Explorer level.

Comment: Smart git looks the best. As I can see its free for personal use.

Comment: TortoisGit offers overlay icons, and it just looks like TortoiseSNV and TortoiseHg

Comment: I would advise against TortoiseGit if you are serious about learning Git.  TortoiseGit is easy to pick-up for SVN users, but teaches you bad habits as you don't fully understand Git's workflows and differences.

Answer (score 27):

GitExtensions is awesome for the true git experience.  TortoiseGit obscures Git, forcing it into a "simple" experience.  TortoiseGit has icon overlays though.  The two work quite nicely together, so just install them both, use them for their strengths, and ignore them for their weaknesses.

Comment: Agree, i install GitExtensions and TortoiseGit in my development machine (home and work place too). It works well and save times, everywhere i can "Git Here"!